# C++ ifstream read only integers

Tags: c++

I have a txt file with numbers with this format 12345678-A plus some random numbers and text in between. I need to read the file and save only the 8 digit integrers to an array. How do I do it?

Current code I have, works if there are numbers only:

```
const int MAX = 1000;

ifstream file("file.txt");

int data;
int index = 0;
int bigdata[MAX];

while (!file.eof() && index < MAX)
{
    file >> data;
    if (data > 20000000 && data < 90000000)
    {
        bigdata[index] = data;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Sample of input text:

```
48251182-D 6,5 6
49315945-F 7 3
45647536-I 3,5 3
45652122-H 7 6,5
77751157-L 2 2,5
75106729-S 2 5
77789857-B 4 3 3,5 3
59932967-V 4 8,5
39533235-Q 8 8,5
45013275-A 5 2
48053435-Y 6 8
48015522-N 3,5 4
48015515-T
48118362-B 7,5 3,5
39931759-Q 5,5 3
39941188-D 3,5 1,5
39143874-I 3,5 4
48281181-O 6,5 6
```

Comment: Actually your code is partially broken anyway. Which resource taught you to write `while (!file.eof())`? [We need to correct it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/560648).

Comment: Probably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084265/reading-integers-from-a-text-file-with-words) on SO.

Comment: @RawN: Unlikely. That's one of millions of obscure answers on SO exhibiting the problem, and there's a comment right underneath it saying "don't do this". I'm looking to be told which book or textbook is misteaching.

Comment: Please show a sample if your txt file.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Would it be okay to fix that answer since the OP has not?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I took it from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/8388/) if I recall correctly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Done!

Comment: @ChristianC.Romero: Okay, best to learn from [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648) (and highly upvoted SO answers) than random forum posts written by newbies ;)

Comment: @ChristianC.Romero can you confirm that the `,` character in `48251182-D 6,5 6` is a decimal point ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution to this problem would be to read the stream character by character and search for 8-digit numbers:

```
static const int MAX = 1000;

int index = 0;
int bigdata[MAX];

int value = 0;
int digits = 0;

for (auto c = file.get(); c != EOF 0; c = file.get())
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        value = (digits ? (value * 10) : 0) + (c - '0');
        ++digits;
        if (digits == 8)
        {
            if (index < MAX)
                bigdata[index++] = value;
            digits = 0;
        }
    } else
    {
        digits = 0;
    }
}
```

The code reads byte by byte and builds an integer number if decimal digits are read. If the digit count reaches 8 the number is stored and the integer number buffer is reset. The integer number buffer is reset immediatly if the character read is not a decimal digit.

istream.get() returns EOF if reading past the end of the file so no need for a call to the .eof() member function.

Please note that this code stores all 8-digit numbers. You have to add another test if you need only numbers in the range 20000000..90000000.

If your lines are always starting with an 8-digit number followed by a minus then you could use this simple solution which I would recommend because of improved readability.

```
std::string buffer;
std::vector<int> target;
while (std::getline(file, buffer))
    target.push_back(atoi(buffer.c_str()));
```

But this solution does not check for the presence of a valid number and simply stores 0 for each line not starting with a number.

Comment: Far too complicated. Let the libraries to the dirty work.

Comment: I misread the question and wrote code to read any 8-digit number from the file. My answer now contains also a simple solution to read numbers from the beginning of each line.

Comment: @AndreasH. I had to process a file with the numbers not being at the beginning of each line and your first suggestion worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If all you need is to strip out the first number in each line then you can use the stream's `operator >>` to read in the integer part and then use `std::getline` to consume the rest of the line.  Using

```
std::vector<int> data;
ifstream fin("file.txt");
int number;
std::string eater;

while (fin >> number) // get first 8 digit number.  stops at the '-'
{
    data.push_back(number);
    std::getline(fin, eater); // consume the rest of the line
    //now we are on the next line
}

// now data has all of the numbers that start each line.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
...
#include <string>
...   
string line;
while (getline(file, line))   // read the whole line
{
   int data = stol(line);     // get number at start of line (stops
                              // automatically at the '-' sign

   // data is the 8 digit number
   // process data here...
   ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for, I had trouble making stol / stoi work in codeblocks and I had to use atoi(line.c_str()); instead. Worked nicely.